# Upgrade PHP-mysql Lib Centos 6

Tags: centos, mysql, php

I just delete all php and mysql and installed it again. but in PHPMyadmin i still get:

```
Your PHP MySQL library version 5.1.69 differs from your MySQL server version 5.5.39. This may cause unpredictable behavior.
```

There are my full spec list:

```
[root@**** ~]# php -v
PHP 5.4.31 (cli) (built: Jul 25 2014 07:41:53) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
[root@***** ~]# rpm -qa | grep php
php54w-5.4.31-1.w6.x86_64
php54w-xml-5.4.31-1.w6.x86_64
php54w-mcrypt-5.4.31-1.w6.x86_64
php54w-mysql-5.4.31-1.w6.x86_64
php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts-6.0.089-1.el6.noarch
php54w-cli-5.4.31-1.w6.x86_64
php54w-mbstring-5.4.31-1.w6.x86_64
php-php-gettext-1.0.11-3.el6.noarch
php54w-pdo-5.4.31-1.w6.x86_64
php54w-tidy-5.4.31-1.w6.x86_64
php-tcpdf-6.0.089-1.el6.noarch
phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.1-1.el6.noarch
php54w-common-5.4.31-1.w6.x86_64
php54w-gd-5.4.31-1.w6.x86_64
php54w-bcmath-5.4.31-1.w6.x86_64

[root@**** ~]# rpm -qa --qf '%{name}-%{version}.%{release}.%{arch}\n' php\* mysql\* | sort
mysql55w-5.5.39.1.w6.x86_64
mysql55w-libs-5.5.39.1.w6.x86_64
mysql55w-server-5.5.39.1.w6.x86_64
php54w-5.4.31.1.w6.x86_64
php54w-bcmath-5.4.31.1.w6.x86_64
php54w-cli-5.4.31.1.w6.x86_64
php54w-common-5.4.31.1.w6.x86_64
php54w-gd-5.4.31.1.w6.x86_64
php54w-mbstring-5.4.31.1.w6.x86_64
php54w-mcrypt-5.4.31.1.w6.x86_64
php54w-mysql-5.4.31.1.w6.x86_64
php54w-pdo-5.4.31.1.w6.x86_64
php54w-tidy-5.4.31.1.w6.x86_64
php54w-xml-5.4.31.1.w6.x86_64
phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.1.1.el6.noarch
php-php-gettext-1.0.11.3.el6.noarch
php-tcpdf-6.0.089.1.el6.noarch
php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts-6.0.089.1.el6.noarch
```

Can anyone tell me what i can do to upgrade my php-mysql lib?

**Note when replacing**

```
    [root@**** ~]# yum replace php-common --replace-with=php54w-common
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.dk.telia.net
 * epel: mirror.proserve.nl
 * extras: ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de
 * rpmforge: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.informatik.hs-fulda.de
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Replacing packages takes time, please be patient...
Error: Package 'php-common' is not installed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use additional repositories for non-standard CentOS packages and want to use newer releases of some components you might benefit from reading [their announcements](https://webtatic.com/packages/php54/) too:

> **Update 2013-07-21** – A new package “php54w-mysqlnd” has been added as an alternative to “php54w-mysql”. This will instead provide mysql, mysqli, and pdo_mysql built against the PHP MySql native driver rather than the system default libmysqlclient. It will replace “php54w-mysql55″, as it will work with MySQL 5.0/5.1/5.5 server)

Comment: ive installed it from there but without luck?

Comment: Did you remove the php54w-mysql package as well?

Comment: i removed everything that had with PHP and SQL. is there any way i can upgrade the client? i can see that i have the following right now:  libmysqlclient16-5.1.69-1.w6.x86_64